# Use NPM with zsh shell in ubuntu windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, zsh

So I recently started using the zsh to code in python, i had to configure the environment variables for it and now im trying to start a small project in javascript and it won't let me use npm.
Trying to initialize the repo will throw this error at me:

```
npm init -y
zsh: /mnt/c/program files/nodejs//npm: bad interpreter: /bin/sh^M: no such file or directory
```

And of course it won't let me install packages.
Any suggestions? as I didn't find anything that could help me solve the problem.

Comment: Looks like you have Windows line endings in your project files (^M). You will need to remove them.

Comment: And how would you go about that? Wouldn't it be right since I'm using windows ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like what i had to do is install nodejs back again as this is a new shell, zsh didn't have it installed: If anyone has a similar issue you might wanna try the following :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```